# MagicalRecord NSFetchedResultsController initWithFetchRequest returning nil

Tags: objective-c, magicalrecord

Using MagicalRecord version 2.3 NSFetchedResultsController initWithFetchRequest does not return any objects, despite knowing there are objects available.

```
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [SomeObject MR_requestAllSortedBy:@"created" ascending:NO];
//[request setFetchLimit:100];
[request setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
NSFetchedResultsController* fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: fetchRequest managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

NSInteger rowCount = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count
```

What am i missing?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: What is the code that is not returning any objects? Also, format your code with CMD-K.

Comment: Also, are you running `performFetch` on the FRC?

Comment: Sorry code formatted now. Just checking the returning rows with fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count returns nil

Comment: And yes the fetch is running on the TableView Controller

Comment: Cool, so when you say that no objects are being returned... Which bit is telling you that? What bit of code? And how do you know that it knows about the objects? The fetch needs to run on the fetched results controller. You should have the line `[fetchedResultsController performFetch:...` do you have that somewhere?

Comment: I've just edited the code to include NSInteger rowCount = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count which is 0, if i run PO fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count in the console it just returns <nil>

Comment: Yes, but did you run the performFetch method that I've mentioned in my previous comments? That needs to be run to actually perform the fetch and go and get the objects.

Comment: Thanks, was blind! Was doing it in the wrong place.. sorted now.

Comment: I've added an answer now so that people don't miss it. Please could you accept it so that the question shows as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After creating the FRC you need to make sure you run the `performFetch` method. This is the method that actually tells the FRC to go and get the objects.

```
if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&someError]) {
    // handle the error.
}
```

If you're using MagicalRecord then you can save a lot of code by doing...

```
NSFetchedResultController *frc = [SomeObject MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"created" ascending:NO];
[frc performFetch:nil];
```

LOL! Just searching around and found this site... http://samwize.com/2014/03/29/implementing-nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-magicalrecord/

Seems you got there before me.

Comment: I've been struggling for 1 hour why it doesn't fetch!
Thanks a lot! :)